# Angular 2 preloader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, preloader

I don't know how to put preloader(simple image) before *ngFor. If the data is fetched from the server my list appears but so long as the data is not loaded picture is displayed.

---

```
<tr ngFor='#product of products' >                        
    <td >                         
         {{product.id+ " " + product.title}}
    </td>            
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ngIf. Here is a template you can use

```
<table *ngIf="products.length != 0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="#product of products">
        <td>{{product.id}}</td>
        <td>{{product.title}}</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<loading-image *ngIf="products.length == 0"></loading-image>
```

where `loading-image` is your a component that you define yourself

```
@Component({
    selector: 'loading-image',
    directives: [],
    template: `
    <img src="{{loadImg}}">
  `
})
export class LoadingImage {
    loadImg = 'assets/img/your-loading-image.gif';
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new in Angular. What is <loading-image> is this a name of selector in new component? Can I put for example  img tag <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"  /> somewhere directly in my HTML template?

Comment: I edited my answer.
Yes, you can put  <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> instead. But if you use the same loading image in another componant, you might want to create a componant for it.